# Can't run opencv sample applications on Nexus 9

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I'm working on an opencv app for android. I'm trying to run the sample opencv apps on a nexus 9 tablet(OS is lollipop, chip is tegra k1). I installed opencv manager and it says under installed packages that "Built in opencv library(optimized)" is installed (library version: 2.4.9.0 rev 1 , target hardware: Tegra). But whenever I try to run any app that uses opencv (opencv for tegra demo, ocv face detection, opencvd2, ocv 15 puzzle) it gives me a message that

> "opencv library package was not found! Try to install it?"

When I tap "yes" it takes me to google play to download the opencv manager which I already have installed!

I've already tred installing the ocv 2.4 pack armeabi-v7a but it didn't help. There are user comments on the opencv manager app that it doesn't work on the nexus 9. Is this a known issue? I saw somewhere that the nexus 9 doesn't support CUDA (https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/782024/tegra-tools/tadp-for-nexus9-wishlist-/). Could that be it? It was my impression that CUDA speeds things up but that opencv should be able to run without it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this is due to the fact that the Denver, which Nexus 9 has, is on ARMv8-A.
I hope the next release of Android4OpenCV contains a pre-built binary for this architecture.

In the meantime, you could possibly build it by setting the target architecture as ''arm64-v8a" with [this latest CMake toolchain file](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/commit/96adeb71ca643e0c3ed51f75b5f04a84bb661e15#diff-3a60ec03457cb5c4c9f12c5d698bec95R88).

I didn't try it yet though, it would be helpful if somebody who tried this can share his/her experience.
Thanks!